# Why Animation is speed up after first run?

Tags: android

In my activity i am playing animations.. When i am starting the activity for first time,all the animations are playing with the given duration. But it is speed up when i am repeating  each and every animation for more time.. This is my activity.... And In my code i haven't provide all object and variable declaration to reduce the code...

public class Exercise extends Activity {
    /** Called when the activity is first created. */

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.exercise);

    exercise_Layout=(RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.exerciselayout);

    exercise_Layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.exercise_bg);

    if(getIntent().getStringExtra("TIPS").equals("Fun"))
    {
     count=0;
     System.out.println("This is Fun");
    }
    else if(getIntent().getStringExtra("TIPS").equals("Tips"))
    {
     count=1;

    }
gym.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            exercise_Layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.exercise_bg);
            gym_View.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.gymanim);
            gym_Animation=(AnimationDrawable)gym_View.getBackground();
            gym_Animation.start();
            //playing sounds
            mp.reset();
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.gym);   
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);    

        }
    });

    run.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                            exercise_Layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.exercise_bg);
            run_View.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.runanim);
            run_Animation=(AnimationDrawable)run_View.getBackground();
            run_Animation.start();
            //playing sounds
            mp.reset();
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.thread_music);  
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);    

        }
    });

    jogg.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            jogg_View.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.jogroadanim);
            jogg_Animation=(AnimationDrawable)jogg_View.getBackground();
            jogg_Animation.start();
            //playing sounds
            mp.reset();
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.jogging);   
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);    

        }
    });

    swim.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            exercise_Layout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.swimingpool);
            swim_View.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

            swim_View.setBackgroundResource(R.anim.swimanim);
            swim_Animation=(AnimationDrawable)swim_View.getBackground();
            swim_Animation.start();
            //playing sounds
            mp.reset();
            mp=MediaPlayer.create(getApplicationContext(),R.raw.swimming);  
            try {
                mp.prepare();
            } catch (IllegalStateException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            mp.start();
            mp.setLooping(true);    

        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I´m not sure, but if you use `CountDownTimers` and you press multiple times on it, you start them twice or more times. Maybe its the same issue to your animations. I see there `swim_Animation.start();` for example.. try `swim_Animation.stop();` before reactivating it. I hope I didn't misunderstand you explanation..